python random.shuffle from lists in a text file
Trying to do a random.shuffle which works well if the list is declared.
In example 2, I'm trying to do this from a file that has 1000 entries
with the first two lines shown.
Is the txt file formatted wrong? I cant get this to work.
I've tried many examples found on the net.
import random

#example 1

list1 = ['sub', 'gig', 'bug']

random.shuffle(list1)

print('list1:', list1)

#Results

list1: ['bug', 'gig', 'sub']

#example 2
#masterwords.txt has this on line 1 and 2
['bug', 'gig', 'sub']

['frog', 'dog', 'cat']

with open("masterwords.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as file:

lines = []

   for line in file:

      line = line.strip()

      lines.append(line)

      random.shuffle(lines)

print(lines)

#Results:

["['frog', 'dog', 'cat']", "['bug', 'gig', 'sub']", '']


Take a look at the literal_eval function from the ast module

The data in the file are string representations of Python lists. You need to convert them into runtime lists. You can do this with the ast.literal_eval() function.
Let's assume the input file contains:
['bug', 'gig', 'sub']
['frog', 'dog', 'cat']

Then:
from ast import literal_eval
from random import shuffle

with open("masterwords.txt") as mw:
    for line in mw:
        lst = literal_eval(line)
        shuffle(lst)
        print(lst)

Possible output:
['sub', 'gig', 'bug']
['cat', 'dog', 'frog']


this worked perfectly. would it make a difference if i changed the masterwords.txt to masterwords.py and imported it then ran the code? Anyway, your solution was perfect, thank you!!
